# Take ownership of referenced Eigen3 matrix

Tags: python, c++, move-semantics, eigen3, pybind11

How to pass an eigen matrix A into a function by reference, and then steal ownership of A?

I am writing a C++ extension to Python that takes in two `std::vector<Eigen::Ref<Mat> >` and returns a `std::vector<Mat>`. Each element of the returned vector can be a new matrix or an old matrix referenced in the input vectors.

The example from pybind11 mentioned pass-by-reference between C++ and Python with `Eigen::Ref` here ([pybind11 doc](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/eigen.html)).

I try a modification of an example (from an [old bug report](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=956)). But the source is not moved to the target. This is because the source matrix is not empty at the end.

Test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

typedef Eigen::MatrixXd Mat;

Mat func(Eigen::Ref<Mat> ref) {
    Mat target(std::move(ref));
    return target;
}

int main() {
  const std::size_t n = 2;
  Mat source = Mat::Zero(n, n);
  Mat target = func(source);
  std::cout << "source\n" << source << "\n";
  std::cout << "target\n" << target << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
source
0 0
0 0
target
0 0
0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because the memory layout of `Ref<MatrixXd>` is more general than `MatrixXd` and it does not even own the data that it references! So the only solution for you is to pass a `MatrixXd&`.

Answer (score 1):

`ref` inside your function is a local variable. You can move it, that's OK. But you cannot steal ownership because it's passed by value, you don't have access to the object as it exists in the caller's workspace. Also, you are moving the reference to a constructor of `Mat`, which will simply create a new matrix by copy (I presume, since you cannot move an object of one type to an object of a different type).

What you see happening is because `ref` shares the data with `source` in the caller's workspace. These are two different objects that point to the same data.

If you were to return the reference object (rather than create a new matrix initialized with the reference object as you do), then the reference could outlive the original object referenced, and cause trouble.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why that std::move won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This works in C++:

Test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>

typedef Eigen::MatrixXd Mat;

void print_mats(std::string const& s, const std::vector<Mat>& v) {
    std::cout << s << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "matrix #" << i << "\n";
        std::cout << v[i] << "\n";
    }
}

std::vector<Mat> func(std::vector<Mat>& source) {
    std::vector<Mat> target;
    target.emplace_back(std::move(source[0]));
    return target;
}

int main() {
    const std::size_t n = 2;
    std::vector<Mat> source;
    // can't move Mat::Zero(n, n), which is a const expression.
    // no need for source.emplace_back(std::move(Mat::Zero(n, n)));
    source.emplace_back(Mat::Zero(n, n));
    print_mats("source before", source);
    std::vector<Mat> target = func(source);
    print_mats("source after", source);
    print_mats("target", target);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
source before
matrix #0
0 0
0 0
source after
matrix #0

target
matrix #0
0 0
0 0
```

Comment: Doesn't work at pybind11 side. pybind11 make copy of the array within the `std::vector`. Using `Eigen::Ref` can avoid making copy, but that won't let me use `std::move`.

Comment: Using a std::vector<Eigen::Ref > won't let me allocate a new array and append that to the vector within the function.

Comment: new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506984/pass-a-list-of-numpy-array-without-copying